# Galaxy S Duos is not charging properly

Tags: battery

My Galaxy S Duos doesn't display a charging sign when I plug it in, even though it is charging fine. Secondly, when I use it while plugged in it charges very slowly. A 1% increase takes 4-5 minutes.

When I do a random reboot, the battery percentage decreases, especially when it's at 100%

Why this problem occurring?

Comment: Please don't ask people to contact you outside the site to provide or obtain answers. Relevant content should be posted here directly, so that everyone can benefit from it. We don't want to merely act as a facilitator for little side conversations.